# Ajax data method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, http

I have an ajax post request that needs to send some data in the format of array[integer] without parameters or keys. Unfortunately the browser hangs on request every time I try. I have had success in postman and in swagger but I can't figure out the data format required to just send this keyless array.

Here is my request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/endpoint?code=" + data,
        data: [1],
        success: function(response) {
           console.log(response);
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.log(status + " " + err);
        }.bind(this)
    });
```

In my Swagger docs the following works

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "[1]" "http://url/endpoint?code=testing"
```

In postman, it looks like the form data posts the array as a key without a value. 
I have been able to implement this in the browser but still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated, It seems like a simple answered question but I can't seem to find any solutions.

Comment: Does putting quotes around the array work, i.e. passing a string instead of an array literal?

Comment: You could also use `JSON.stringify([1])` which would be a much better solution for extensibility reasons.

Comment: My thoughts too. I have tried both of those and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try stringfying your data. Send "[1]"

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. In both cases of not stringifying data and stringifying it, Chrome gives me provisional headers and form data looks like [1]: or "[1]":   both requests hang up

Answer (score 0):

Call `JSON.stringify`, and provide a `contentType` option to specify that header.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/endpoint?code=" + data,
    data: JSON.stringify([1]),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
       console.log(response);
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.log(status + " " + err);
    }.bind(this)
});
```

BTW, instead of using `.bind(this)` on each callback function, you can use the option `context: this` to pass it automatically.

Comment: Hey thank you. This wasn't the right answer for me but it lead to me finding out the real source of the problem. I'm piping the streams from my own server to another and piping the response back. Somewhere along the line, it fails. I'll investigate some more.